# passing byte[] to smart contract using nethereum

Tags: solidity, remix, arrays, nethereum, c#

I made a solidity function that allow a user to send multiple transactions with the same nonce as a singleton Tx signer:

```
function multipleTransferPreSigned
  (
    bytes[] _signature,
    address[] _to,
    uint[] _value,
    uint[] _fee,
    uint256 _nonce
  )
    public
    returns (bool)
  {
      for(uint256 i=0; i < _signature.length; i++)
      {
        require(_to[i] != address(0));
        require(interfaceData.getSignatures(_signature[i]) == false);
   

        bytes32 hashedTx = transferPreSignedHashing(address(this), _to[i], 
          _value[i], _fee[i], _nonce + i);

        address from = recover(hashedTx, _signature[i]);
   
        require(from != address(0));

        balances[from] = balances[from].sub(_value[i]).sub(_fee[i]);
        balances[_to[i]] = balances[_to[i]].add(_value[i]);
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].add(_fee[i]);
    
        interfaceData.setSignatures(_signature[i], true);
        signatures[_signature] = true;

        emit Transfer(from, _to[i], _value[i]);
        emit Transfer(from, msg.sender, _fee[i]);
        emit TransferPreSigned(from, _to[i], msg.sender, _value[i], _fee[i]);
      }
        return true;
    }
```

when I pass the arguments using remix IDE like this:

```
["0x7cd81c609d1b65cdaed5c09527bf2bd075279a03ce5c0b7474655a91784a54b36e35e903f754bfc3411ae64f9b1627bf81c5a93c77441c2ba0822f61ed2707e51c", "0xf62e24934659fe88bf28de2dc8c37972c30351238de8341414780c7c37902a9b1f02b51e303618eec0be11d0ae5abf57e4aa39aaae4aed4413016d04c732abe31c"]

["0x27e739f9dF8135fD1946b0b5584BcE49E22000af", "0x0356a6cfcf3fd04ea88044a59458abb982aa9d96"]

["2000000000000000000", "2000000000000000000"]

["1000000000000000000", "1000000000000000000"]

628
```

the function working as expected. But when I use Nethereum I do not understand how to pass the arguments. It doesn't work.

My C# code:

```
 public async Task<string> MultipleTransferPreSignedAsync(List<string> fromPK, List<string> to, List<int> amount, List<int> fee, CancellationToken token)
    {
        Account SpitballAccountt = new Account(SpitballPrivateKey);
        var web3 = new Web3(SpitballAccountt);

        List<BigInteger> amountList = new List<BigInteger>();
        List<BigInteger> feeList = new List<BigInteger>();
        List<byte[]> sigList = new List<byte[]>();

        var txCount = await web3.Eth.Transactions.GetTransactionCount.SendRequestAsync(GetAddress(SpitballPrivateKey));
        var nonce = txCount.Value;
        for (int i = 0; i < fromPK.Count; i++)
        {
            var amountTransformed = new BigInteger(amount[i] * FromWei);
            amountList.Add(amountTransformed);
            var feeTransformed = new BigInteger(fee[i] * FromWei);
            feeList.Add(feeTransformed);
            nonce = txCount.Value + i;

            string str = "48664c16"
                        + ContractAddress.RemoveHexPrefix()
                        + to[i].RemoveHexPrefix()
                        + amountTransformed.ToString("X64")
                        + feeTransformed.ToString("X64")
                        + nonce.ToString("X64");

            var byteStr = HexByteConvertorExtensions.HexToByteArray(str);
            var sha3 = new Nethereum.Util.Sha3Keccack();
            var res = sha3.CalculateHash(byteStr);
            var messageSigner = new MessageSigner();
            
            sigList.Add(messageSigner.Sign(res, fromPK[i]).HexToByteArray());

        }

        nonce = txCount.Value;

        var function = await GetFunctionAsync("multipleTransferPreSigned", token).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var receiptFirstAmountSend = await function.SendTransactionAndWaitForReceiptAsync(SpitballPrivateKey, MaxGas, token, sigList.ToArray(), to.ToArray(), amountList.ToArray(), feeList.ToArray(), nonce).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var contract = await GetContractAsync(web3, token);
        var bidAddedEventLog = contract.GetEvent("TransferPreSigned");
        var filterInput =
           bidAddedEventLog.CreateFilterInput(new BlockParameter(receiptFirstAmountSend.BlockNumber), BlockParameter.CreateLatest());
        var logs = await bidAddedEventLog.GetAllChanges<TransferPreSignedDTO>(filterInput);
        return receiptFirstAmountSend.BlockHash;
    }

       public static async Task<TransactionReceipt> SendTransactionAndWaitForReceiptAsync(this Function function, string privateKey, double maxGas,
        CancellationToken receiptRequestCancellationToken, params object[] functionInput)
    {
       
        var gas = new HexBigInteger((BigInteger)maxGas);
        var publicAddress = Web3.GetAddressFromPrivateKey(privateKey);

        using (var tokenSource = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(receiptRequestCancellationToken))
        {
                return await function.SendTransactionAndWaitForReceiptAsync(publicAddress, gas, null,
                    tokenSource, functionInput).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

    }
```

Any help will be great.
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example :

```
    web3.TransactionManager.DefaultGas = BigInteger.Parse("290000");
    web3.TransactionManager.DefaultGasPrice = BigInteger.Parse("0");  
    web3.TransactionManager.UseLegacyAsDefault = true;
    Contract MyContract = web3.Eth.GetContract(ABI, this.address);
    var addcpt = Mycontract.GetFunction("fct");
    var transactionHash = fct.SendTransactionAsync(senderAddress, name).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    var action = Mycontract.GetFunction("fct");

    var receipt =action.SendTransactionAndWaitForReceiptAsync(senderAddress, new HexBigInteger(900000), null, null, byteArray).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```